# Rust: Is there a way to call a static function on a macro type argument?

Tags: macros, rust

This code:

```
#![feature(macro_rules)]

macro_rules! new(
    ($my_type:ty) => ( $my_type::new() );
)

struct Foo {
    blah: int
}

impl Foo {
    fn new() -> Foo {
        return Foo { blah: 0 }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_foo = new!(Foo);
    println!("Foo's value: {}", my_foo.blah);
}
```

Looks good enough, but it fails with this error:

```
test.rs:4:25: 4:32 error: unexpected token: `Foo`
test.rs:4     ($my_type:ty) => ( $my_type::new() );
                                  ^~~~~~~
```

If I go into the macro and replace `$my_type` with `Foo` it compiles and runs just fine, so `Foo` is clearly valid in that position. Unless `Foo` comes from macro substitution, apparently.

If I run `rustc test.rs --pretty expanded`, it doesn't show me the expanded macro. It just gives me the same error message. I suspect this means it's generating the message before it expands the macro, but it might just be that it doesn't show me anything unless the compile succeeds. Though that would severely limit the usefulness of `--pretty expanded`.

Based on other experiments, I can use the macro type arguments in basically every other place one would expect a type to work. You just can't call static functions on them. This seems like a rather arbitrary restriction, and the error message is certainly not helpful.

Why does this restriction exist? And is there a way around it?

Comment: `--pretty expanded` requires the macro expansion to have worked, thus it is normal you get no output when the expansion fails.

Comment: That makes sense, of course... My confusion arose from the fact that the error message implies that the expansion succeeded, but the compilation failed after the expansion. This is based on the fact that the expansion refers to the actual identifier, Foo, as being unexpected, not the un-expanded name, $my_type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Foo::bar()` syntax is creating the path `Foo::bar` and then calling that function, and only works with valid paths, it doesn't work with arbitrary types, e.g. `(u8, i8)::bar()` doesn't work. You can use the `ident` macro non-terminal, which takes a single identifier and can be used whereever an identifier is valid, including inside a path

```
#![feature(macro_rules)]

macro_rules! new(
    ($my_type: ident) => ( $my_type::new() );
)

struct Foo {
    blah: int
}

impl Foo {
    fn new() -> Foo {
        return Foo { blah: 0 }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_foo = new!(Foo);
    println!("Foo's value: {}", my_foo.blah);
}
```

[UFCS](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0132-ufcs.md) offers calling such methods on arbitrary types, via the syntax `<Type>::new()` and so, when that is implemented, replacing your current macro with

```
macro_rules! new(
    ($my_type: ty) => ( <$my_type>::new() );
)
```

should work too.

Comment: I checked [The Rust Macro Guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-macros.html#invocation-syntax) for a list of available fragment specifiers but it only lists the "most common" ones (which admittedly contains `ident`); would you know where to get a definite list?

Comment: @MatthieuM. [the source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/e84e7a00ddec76570bbaa9afea385d544f616814/src/libsyntax/ext/tt/macro_parser.rs#L436-L464).

Comment: That worked! The actual macro in my code is MUCH more complicated, and actually uses the type in a number of places which aren't paths... But surprisingly, switching it from "ty" to "ident" didn't break any of those other cases. Which means the only reason I can think to use "ty" is possible for clarity. Is there any other reason?

Comment: @MichaelPowell, there are things that are not valid `ident`s but are valid types, e.g. a path `foo::Bar`, a reference `&T` or a tuple `(T, U)`. The latter can all be used with a `ty` non-terminal, but not with `ident` which is a single identifier `foo_bar_baz`. All identifiers can be used in type position (they don't necessarily refer to valid types, but macro expansion doesn't know/care) so it is strictly more flexible to use `ident` if the macro will only be called with identifiers.